# GraphQL error: Expected Iterable while using Sequelize findAndCountAll function

Tags: sequelize.js, react-apollo

### My issue

Hi!
I'm trying to implement a simple pagination using Meteor, Apollo, React and Sequelize. I have no problem querying what I want using the *findAll()* function but since I also want the total number of rows affected by my query I am using *findAndCountAll()* but I get this error :

> Unhandled (in react-apollo) Error: GraphQL error: Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field Query.books

#### resolvers.js

```
export const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    async books(root, args, context) {
      return  Book.findAndCountAll({ 
        where: {},
        offset: args.offset,
        limit: args.limit,
      });
    }
  }
};
```

#### My schema

```
export const typeDefs =`
type Book {
  id: String!
  title: String!
  author: String!
  price: Float!
  quantity: Float!
  isbn: String!
  publisher: String!
  description: String
  collectionName: String
  collectionNumber: Int
  serieName: String
  serieNumber: Int
}

type Query {
  books(limit: Int, offset: Int): [Book]
}
`;
```

#### My model

```
const BookModel = db.define('book', {
  title: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
  author: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
  price: { type: Sequelize.FLOAT },
  quantity: { type: Sequelize.FLOAT },
  isbn: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
  publisher: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
  description: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
  collectionName: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
  collectionNumber: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
  serieName: { type: Sequelize.STRING },
  serieNumber: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER },
});
```

#### My graphQL query

```
const allBooks = gql`
  query BooksForDisplay($limit: Int, $offset: Int) {
    books(limit: $limit, offset: $offset) {
      id,
      title,
      author,
      price,
      quantity,
      isbn,
      publisher,
      description,
      collectionName,
      collectionNumber,
      serieName,
      serieNumber
    }
  }
`;
```

I  think something is missing but I cannot find what it is. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Solved it thanks to @Tilekbekov Yrysbek by adding `.then((result) => {
        return result.rows;
      });`
to my findAndCountAll function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAndCountAll` function as a result returns an object with 2 properties `{count: rowsCount, rows: arrayOfModelInstances}`. You should iterate `rows`

Comment: Thanks for replying!
The problem is that I do not iterate the result myself. Since I am using Meteor it does it for me :
`const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers
});`
I just pass it the resolvers.